# Questions about multi-arch docker image as base image in Dockerfile of project

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, buildx

I would like to use [openjdk:15-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/openjdk/15-alpine/images/sha256-6ac8794912d16d92b0805380f7bebbfe3d67d7b1131f248f241d696c22dbf4a5?context=explore) image as the base image for the `Dockerfile` of my java project (because it is lightweighted). But it only supports amd64 CPU architecture while I am using Macbook M2 chip which is armv64 architecture.

Here is the `Dockerfile` of my project, as you can see the base image is [openjdk:15-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/openjdk/15-alpine/images/sha256-6ac8794912d16d92b0805380f7bebbfe3d67d7b1131f248f241d696c22dbf4a5?context=explore) :

```
FROM openjdk:15-alpine

...

...

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/myapp.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

I have two questions:

**Q1.** Is it so that if I want to build multi-arch image for my project, the base image itself has to be already multi-arch supported?

**Q2.** If the answer of above question is "yes", how can I build my own version of `jdk:15-alpine` that supports multi architecture (linux/amd64,linux/arm64), which I can then used as a base image of my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:** yes, that is true. For example, for java, how would the AMD64 binaries in that image work on ARM64?

**Q2:** by taking the original Dockerfile and building it on an ARM machine. Alternatively, you can also use [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/) to build ARM images on AMD.

Comment: Thanks. The answer of Q2 is still vague. I mean I know how to use `buildx` builder to build multi-arch image for my project. But as the answer of Q1 said, for that I first need a base image to support multi-arch,  so, my Q2 is mainly about how to make that jdk 17 alpine base image which can support multi-arch, not how to build my project image.

Comment: Yes, but you did say that you want to build the base image to be used in your actual project, so I answered that.

Comment: To be more clear, based on your answer of Q2,  do you mean take the Dockerfile of `openjdk:15-alpine` to build multi-arch one?  If so, where can I get that? If not, could you please clarify more to be more clear? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.
Unfortunately, you'll have to do some google searches. I'd advise you to instead try out `eclipse-temurin` as the base java image as that distribution is fully open source, [including the Dockerfiles](https://github.com/adoptium/containers/blob/0a0eef5b0673a25403d4b0fe87e4f4e07a4297ab/17/jdk/alpine/Dockerfile.releases.full)

Comment: Thanks. Clear to me now.